# .NET getting and setting RegistryKey values directly in property

Tags: c#, properties, registry

I'm getting and setting a registrykey's value directly in a property. The key is opened on program startup and closed on exit.

```
    public bool AlwaysSyncBeforeRun
    {
        get{ return Convert.ToBoolean(MayaRegistryKey.GetValue("AlwaysSyncBeforeRun")); }
        set { MayaRegistryKey.SetValue("AlwaysSyncBeforeRun", value); }
    }
```

This property is not meant for frequent usage.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea as the developer using your class might not be aware of what is happening inside the property and registry access has security implications. If the application using your class do not have registry access permission, then a simple get on the property will cause an exception.

For this scenario I would better use the property to store the values in memory and provide some Load() method to populate the property and a Save() method that can be called whenever the application is ready to save to registry.

This link from the .NET Framework Design Guidelines might provide additional context: [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054.aspx)

Comment: yes, your suggestion makes sense. Not only is it safer, it's quicker as well. However, the user might lose the settings if the program does not shut down properly.

Comment: Agree, but in that case your best bet is to have a good global exception handler where you always save all settings before letting the application to close. This is simmilar to using the [ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) class in Windows Forms. You can't prevent all possible bad situtations anyway.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

If it is not meant for frequent usage, why do you keep it open?

You do something like that to improve performance. But, in your case, you don't use it frequently. So, I suggest you could open key, read/write value and close it. It will be safe.

Comment: the reason I keep it open is I'm using the same key to store multiple settings.

Answer (score 0):

Alot of people say you should not have functionality at all in a property.

Have you tried editing the registry key while your program has the reference to it open? I have not tried but if your app is locking the key for the duration its running then it may be better to read the key, store it and update it at the end.

Comment: Having functionality in properties is fine if it's just changing values and triggering events. Once you're looping, creating files, ... in a propertry then it's a bad idea.
In this case, I don't think there are performance reasons involved.

That will very likely cause an exception to be fired, I'm aware of that. My program is set to run only on instance of itself, so that's pretty safe. Good programming conventions would suggest I put checks in there.